# what's the best way to remove element(s) i inserted with after()

Tags: jquery

when I click a button, i appended (inserted) after it a div with new div, and i donot want to give id to the new div, because i want this function could be use by other button/anchor/etc.

```
$("#buttonA").click(function(){
$("#div1").after("<div>bla bla bla</div>");
});
```

and then by an event i want to remove the inserted div.
what's the best way to remove inserted div? ... i still cant make it generic, i must apply ID on the new inserted div, and then to remove it i use

```
$("#newid").remove()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mark the inserted element with a tag (in this case, the `inserted` class):

```
$("#buttonA").click(function(){
    $("#div1").after("<div class='inserted'>bla bla bla</div>");
});
```

Then look for the inserted element using the selector of your choice:

```
$("#div1 .inserted").remove();
```

You could also remove every `div` inserted this way:

```
$(".inserted").remove();
```

If your intention is to allow many different events to create many different `div`s all inside the same container, and then remove one particular div, then you are going to need to either generate unique ids for each `div` and map them to the callers for later reference, or simply map the created `div` element to the callers for later reference. It's hard to make a strong suggestion without knowing more about your use case.

Answer (score 5):

Use `.next` to traverse to the div after #div1.

```
$("#div1").next("div").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add only one div, you can make a variable, like this:

```
var newDiv = $("<div>New Div!</div>")

$("#buttonA").click(function(){
 $("#div1").after(newDiv);
});

$("#buttonB").click(function(){
 $(newDiv).remove();
});
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pzMj3/) to see it working.

But that solution will not work if you need multiple elements.